# Unable to index file on git add

Tags: git, docker

i used docker on my spring boot API and MySQL database but when I try to use git add it returns an

```
error: unable to index file 'scheduling-system-server/docker/volume-mysql/mysql.sock'
```

i looked into it but i really don't know what to do in this case

I tried adding some extensions in .gitignore file but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can't index sockets, thats fine. You don't need to. Why are you storing the database files in git anyway?

Comment: I am not the original author of the topic but for your curiosity: I am committing a database to a local git along with a wordpress installation and docker files to get some history of my testdata. Usually not the best idea but I need to version my testdata blobs for to be able to know where the regression occurred (in test data or in code)

Answer (score 0):

Docker Volume was not need to push on git, so you can add it on git ignore

Because where you run from docker-compose up, the volume folders are automatically created with docker, so you can ignore it